# Nested loop to render tiles in a grid

Tags: java, beginner, iteration, scope

This code works but I'm not really sure if I wrote it good enough. It seems a bit vague but I can't really assess it properly. I'm particularly concerned with the `xAxis` variable. I don't like how I have to initialize it inside the first loop. I would rather have it next to `yAxis`. Is this a problem?

```
float yAxis = SPACE_BETWEEN_TILES;
float xAxis;

for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    xAxis = SPACE_BETWEEN_TILES;
    for(int v = 0; v < 3; v++) {
        shapeRenderer.rect(xAxis, yAxis, 10, 10);
        xAxis = TILE_WIDTH_AND_HEIGHT + xAxis;
    }
    yAxis = yAxis + TILE_WIDTH_AND_HEIGHT;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write it this way instead:

```
for (int v = 0; v < 3; v++) {
    for (int h = 0; h < 3; h++) {
        float x = SPACE_BETWEEN_TILES + h * TILE_WIDTH_AND_HEIGHT;
        float y = SPACE_BETWEEN_FILES + v * TILE_WIDTH_AND_HEIGHT;
        shapeRenderer.rect(x, y, 10, 10);
    }
}
```

… because:

- With your repeated addition, floating-point inaccuracies would accumulate.
- It's easier to understand.
- All variables are scoped as narrowly as possible.
- `i` and `v` make a weird pair of variable names.

In addition, you should probably consider using `double`, as `float` is rarely useful.

Answer (score 7):

I think it is mostly fine as it is. I would declare variables at the level they are actually needed, not before. Also, `xAxis = TILE_WIDTH_AND_HEIGHT + xAxis;` can be written as `xAxis += TILE_WIDTH_AND_HEIGHT`.

`i` and `v` are not very good variable names (too short, and they don't fit together). What does `v` even stand for? `vertical`? In that case, I would use `vertical` and `horizontal`.

`TILE_WIDTH_AND_HEIGHT` would be shorter as `TILE_DIMENSION`.

You could restructure it like this if you want to:

```
    for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
            shapeRenderer.rect(SPACE_BETWEEN_TILES + TILE_DIMENSION * x, SPACE_BETWEEN_TILES + TILE_DIMENSION * y, 10, 10);
        }
    }
```

The performance loss from transforming additions to multiplications should be fine in most cases.

Answer (score 3):

With a little rearrangement, you can initialize `xAxis` both in and out of the loop, like `yAxis`:

```
float yAxis = SPACE_BETWEEN_TILES;
float xAxis = SPACE_BETWEEN_TILES;

for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for(int v = 0; v < 3; v++) {
        shapeRenderer.rect(xAxis, yAxis, 10, 10);
        xAxis = TILE_WIDTH_AND_HEIGHT + xAxis;
    }
    yAxis = yAxis + TILE_WIDTH_AND_HEIGHT;
    xAxis = SPACE_BETWEEN_TILES;
}
```

This isn't really an issue, but I would probably initialize `xAxis` first because you write the coordinates as {x, y}, so this keeps that order:

```
float xAxis = SPACE_BETWEEN_TILES;
float yAxis = SPACE_BETWEEN_TILES;

for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        shapeRenderer.rect(xAxis, yAxis, 10, 10);
        xAxis = TILE_WIDTH_AND_HEIGHT + xAxis;
    }

    xAxis = SPACE_BETWEEN_TILES;
    yAxis = yAxis + TILE_WIDTH_AND_HEIGHT;
}
```

Also, when you have two nested loops, it is traditional to use variable names `i` and `j` for your counters.  If your counters represent any besides counters, you may want to name them a bit more specifically.